# How do I feed three-dimensional input layer into a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have training data where each example is a `12x3` two-dimensional array. Let's say I have 1000 of these training examples so my input matrix is a three-dimensional `1000x12x3` matrix. I am trying to feed this into a Neural Network (similar to the one outlined in the diagram below). However the first layer of the neural net is expecting the input matrix to be *two dimensional* since the hidden layer with which it will be multiplied is also two-dimensional.  [image]

How do I resolve this? Should I force each input example to be single dimensional, by flattening it out into a `1x36` array? Or should the hidden layers themselves be three-dimensional in order to match the input?

Comment: Are you familiar to `CNNs`?

Comment: @Media I don't think this a cnn problem...The OP is probably confusing that in a NN flattening the array will not result in any change of results

Comment: Maybe, but the subsequent layers are like what we see in CNNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common options are:

1. Change the input shape. Use [numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to transform the original shape three-dimensional into a two-dimensional.
2. Change the model architecture. Each layer that receives a three-dimensional representation will have to be three-dimensional size or add a layer than learns a two-dimensional representation.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't input all of the examples into one layer at once. You input the first example, feed it forward then feed it backward, then you input the next example and so on. Like the neural network needs to be able to actually learn you can't just run one iteration and have it make accurate predictions.

If you're doing it from scratch it would look something like

```
input_data = np.array() #shape of 1000x12x3
for i in range(1000):
    neuralnet = neuralnet(input=input_data[i]) #input data with shape 12x3
```